# Train question answering model with custom dataset

Tags: python, transformer, question-answering, chatbot

How can I train a question-answering ML model with a custom dataset?

I have gathered nearly 110GB of text data, containing documentation manuals for software products and I am looking into different ML algorithms for question-answering.

The problem is that I don't know how to process these files to make a dataset that will be later used to train the model. There are no labels or anything in the data.

Comment: Question-answering models require training data where you explicitly have a question and the answer to it. If you don't have such data, then you should be looking into different types of models, probably retrieval-based chatbot techniques.

Comment: @noe Aren't there any non-supervised methods for this task?

Comment: You can resort to large language models, either as a service like [GPT-3](https://openai.com/api/) or on-premise using [BLOOM](https://bigscience.huggingface.co/blog/bloom) or something alike, to create a QA dataset from your data, and then train a QA model on that.

Comment: I prepared an answer with the information I gave before and some extra about novel retrieval approaches based on large LMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question-answering models require training data where you explicitly have a question and the answer to it. If you don't have such data, then you should be looking into different types of models, probably retrieval-based chatbot techniques.

One option to create a QA dataset would be to use large language models, either as a service like GPT-3 or on-premise using BLOOM or something alike, to create questions and answers from your data, and then train a QA model on that.

Also, depending on what you want exactly as a result, you may use a large language model to generate text to use as the base for document retrieval, as they do in the article [*Generate rather than Retrieve: Large Language Models are Strong Context Generators*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10063)(published at ICLR'23)